# I'm trying to write a simple binary search and I can't get it to return the position, it finds it but won't return it

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I'm trying to write a simple binary search function to find the value in an array and return it's position, or return -1 if it's not there. With console logs I can see that it's working inside, but not returning what I want. It always returns undefined...

```
function binarySearch(arr, q) {
    // set left right middle
    let left = 0,
        right = arr.length - 1,
        middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
    // check if the middle is q
    if (arr[middle] === q) {
        return middle;
    }
    console.log(checkMiddle(left, right, middle));

    let answer = checkMiddle(left, right, middle);

    function checkMiddle(l, r, m) {
        console.log(r - l);
        if (r - l === 1) {
            console.log('not found');
            return -1;
        }
        if (arr[m] === q) {
            // if yes return middle
            console.log('found');
            console.log(m);
            return m;
        }

        //if not find if q is > or < middle
        if (q > arr[m]) {
            // if > move left to middle
            l = m;

            //move middle to new middle
        } else {
            //if < move right to middle
            r = m;
        }
        m = Math.floor((r + l) / 2);
        //search again
        console.log(l, r, m);

        checkMiddle(l, r, m);
    }

    return answer;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 55, 192, 5000, 666666, 8888888, 1055556565456],
    q = 10;
console.log(binarySearch(arr, q));
```

Comment: Your checkMiddle method is not returning anything hence the answer is undefined

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi But on line 23 i have `console.log(m)`; and then on line 24 i have `return m`; 23 will console.log what I want to return, but it's not returning on 24

Comment: Since you are using recursion , return can also mean that you are returning to previous call stack

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi okay, how would I fix it? I'm so lost

Comment: Please check here once https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-for-binary-search-recursive-and-iterative/

Answer (score 2):

It returns undefined because you are not returning anything from your function nor storing the answer in a variable.

Using return in your recursive function only returns to the previous call stack.

Define a global variable and let your recursive function store the answer in it at each call, so you can return this after the function is done.

Modified code below.

```js
function binarySearch(arr, q) {
    // set left right middle
    let left = 0,
        right = arr.length - 1,
        middle = Math.floor(arr.length / 2);
    // check if the middle is q
    if (arr[middle] === q) {
        return middle;
    }
    //console.log(checkMiddle(left, right, middle));

    let answer = 0; // global variable which is modified by the checkMiddle function
    checkMiddle(left, right, middle);
    
    function checkMiddle(l, r, m) {
        console.log(r - l);
        if (r - l === 1) {
            console.log('not found');
            answer = -1;
            return;
        }
        if (arr[m] === q) {
            // if yes return middle
            console.log('found');
            console.log(m);
            answer = m;
            return;
        }

        //if not find if q is > or < middle
        if (q > arr[m]) {
            // if > move left to middle
            l = m;

            //move middle to new middle
        } else {
            //if < move right to middle
            r = m;
        }
        m = Math.floor((r + l) / 2);
        //search again
        console.log(l, r, m);

        checkMiddle(l, r, m);
    }
    console.log("answer : "+answer);
    return answer;
}

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 55, 192, 5000, 666666, 8888888, 1055556565456],
    q = 10;
console.log(binarySearch(arr, q));
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Do I even need to use recursion here?

Comment: No , you can use iterative approach also @Rick . Check this please https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-in-javascript/

Comment: For a binary search, it's more efficient to not use recursion as it's not needed. I figured you were just using this as an example to learn about recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a simpler way.

```js
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 55, 192, 5000, 666666, 8888888, 1055556565456];


    function binarySearch(arr, k, s, e){
        
      s = s || 0;
      e = e || arr.length;
      
      m = s + Math.floor((e - s) / 2);
        
        if (arr[m] === k)
            return m;
        
        if (k > arr[m]){
            return (m+1 < e)?binarySearch(arr, k, m+1, e):-1;
        }else if (m-1 >= s){
            return binarySearch(arr, k, s, m-1);
        }
        
        return -1;
    }


    console.log('answer: '+binarySearch(arr, 3));   //  2
    console.log('answer: '+binarySearch(arr, 10));  // -1
    console.log('answer: '+binarySearch(arr, 55));  //  7
```

Here's an example trying to find '40' at each step in the iteration.
(where V is the value in the array being checked)

```
S = 0, E = 13, V = 7  (40 is higher than 7)
Search upper half...
S = 7, E = 13, V = 666666 (40 is lower than 666666)
Search lower half...
S = 7, E = 9, V = 192 (40 is lower than 192)
Search lower half...
S = 7, E = 7, V = 55 (40 is lower than 55)
Not found.
```

Comment: This seems good, however I don't see where it's accounted for if k is either 0 or arr.length-1 when first called. or if there happens to be a case where s or e is q.

Comment: Doesn't matter what K is, that's the value being searched. (poor variable names I know)  S and E are indices of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function binSearch(arr, key){
    var mid;
    var l = 0, r = arr.length-1;
  
  
  
    
    if(arr.length == 1) return arr[0];
    while (l < r){
        mid = parseInt(l + (r-l)/2);
        // console.log(mid);
        if(arr[mid] == key) return mid;
        if(arr[mid] > key) r--;
        if(arr[mid] < key) l++;
    }

    return mid;
    }

var ans = binSearch([2,5,6,8,9], 2);
console.log(ans)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).